# Select all rows that have multiple sub-relations satisfying some constraints

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let’s say I have a list of baskets that can contain fruits with a certain weight:

```
Table baskets
(id, name)
----------------
1, 'apples, oranges and more'
2, 'apples and small oranges'
3, 'apples and bananas'
4, 'only oranges'
5, 'empty'

Table basket_fruits
(id, basket, fruit, weight)
----------------
1, 1, 'apple', 2
2, 1, 'apple', 3
3, 1, 'orange', 2
4, 1, 'banana', 2
5, 2, 'apple', 2
6, 2, 'orange', 1
7, 3, 'apple', 2
8, 3, 'banana', 2
9, 4, 'orange', 2
```

[SQL Fiddle with this data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f0500/1/0)

I’m struggling to come up with *reasonably efficient* queries for these two scenarios:

1. I want to fetch all baskets that contain *at least one `apple` AND at least one `orange`, each above a given weight*. So the expected result for  `weight >= 2` is

   ```
   1, 'apples, oranges and more'
   ```

   and for `weight >= 1` it’s

   ```
   1, 'apples, oranges and more'
   2, 'apples and small oranges'
   ```
2. I want to fetch all baskets that contain *no fruit above a given weight*. So for `weight >= 2` I would expect

   ```
   5, 'empty'
   ```

   and for `weight >= 3` it should return

   ```
   2, 'apples and small oranges'
   3, 'apples and bananas'
   4, 'only oranges'
   5, 'empty'
   ```

The weight constraint is just a placeholder for "each sub-relation must meet certain constraints". In practice, we need to restrict the sub-relation by date range, status, etc. but I didn’t want to complicate the example any further.

(I’m using postgresql, in case the solution needs to be database-specific.)

Comment: "above a given weight"...is this the weight of each individual fruit, or the total weight of the basket? It's not clear.

Comment: @ADyson, each must be above the weight. I’ve reformulated the question accordingly and added an explanation for the constraint.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend using `group by` and `having` for this purpose.

For your first question, this query should work:

```
SELECT b.name
FROM baskets b INNER JOIN
     basket_fruits bf
     ON b.id = bf.basket
GROUP BY b.name
HAVING SUM( (bf.fruit = 'apple' AND bf.weight >= 2)::int ) > 0 AND
       SUM( (bf.fruit = 'orange' AND bf.weight >= 2)::int ) > 0 ;
```

The second is a little more complicated, because there are no rows.  But a `left join` and `coalesce()` suffice so you can express it in the same format:

```
SELECT b.name
FROM baskets b LEFT JOIN
     basket_fruits bf
     ON b.id = bf.basket
GROUP BY b.name
HAVING SUM( (COALESCE(bf.weight, 0) >= 2)::int ) = 0
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Your solutions are very expensive and slow and don’t mix well with my requirement to fetch the full basket row. But your "SUM(fruit = …)" idea was _really_ valuable and helped me find an solution that has 10-20% the cost (according to the query analyzer).

Answer (score 1):

Here are my solutions so far:

1. All baskets containing both fruits with `weight >= 2` (thanks to Gordon Linoff’s suggestions):

   ```
   SELECT b.* FROM baskets b
   INNER JOIN (
       SELECT basket FROM basket_fruits
       WHERE weight >= 2
       GROUP BY basket
       HAVING SUM((fruit = 'apple')::int) > 0 AND SUM((fruit = 'orange')::int) > 0
   ) bf ON b.id = bf.basket
   ```

   [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f0500/18/0)
2. All baskets without fruits with `weight >= 2`:

   ```
   SELECT b.* FROM baskets b
   LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT basket, fruit FROM basket_fruits
       WHERE weight >= 2
   ) bf ON b.id = bf.basket
   WHERE fruit IS NULL
   ```

   [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f0500/17/0)

If anyone has more efficient ideas, I’d love to hear them.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.name
    FROM baskets b
       INNER JOIN basket_fruits f
           ON b.id = f.basket
GROUP BY b.name
HAVING SUM(f.wage) >= 3
OR b.id = 5
```

Is it what you expected?

Comment: Thanks, but that assumes knowledge about the empty baskets and  doesn’t produce _any_ of the specified outcomes.